# How to pass arguments for a bashscript in java?

Tags: java, bash, apache-kafka

I have follwoing command to be run via my java program;

***./kafka-topics.sh --zookeeper zk1.xx.com:2181,zk2.xx.com:2181,zk3.xx.com:2181 --delete --topic testTopic***

I call this bash script like;

```
ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder(CConstants.KAFKA_TOPIC_SH);
builder.command("--zookeeper","zk1.xx.com:2181,zk2.xx.com:21811,zk3.xx.com:2181",
                "--delete", "--topic", "testTopic");
        builder.start();
```

But i get following error;

```
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "--zookeeper": error=2, No such file or directory
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1048) ~[?:1.8.0_66]
    at
```

How can I run the bash script with the parameters?

Here

- --zookeeper,--delet,e --topic are arguments
- Others are parameters for those aruments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you invoke the *command* method you overwrite the *command* passed to the [ProcessBuilder](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html) constructor. There is a *vararg* variant of the constructor where you can also pass the command arguments:

```
new ProcessBuilder(CConstants.KAFKA_TOPIC_SH, "--zookeeper",
   "zk1.xx.com:2181,zk2.xx.com:21811,zk3.xx.com:2181", "--delete", "--topic",   "testTopic")
   .start();
```

Answer (score 3):

The error you are getting shows that your first parameter is interpreted as command name.
Try this:

```
ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder();
builder.command(CConstants.KAFKA_TOPIC_SH,"--zookeeper","zk1.xx.com:2181,zk2.xx.com:21811,zk3.xx.com:2181",
                "--delete", "--topic", "testTopic");
        builder.start();
```

Answer (score 1):

you can directly invoke the Kafka API instead of encapsulating the java command into a bash script. For example,

String[] options = new String[]{
    "--create",
    "--zookeeper",
    "zk_host:port",
    "--partitions",
    "1",
    "--topic",
    "test",
    "--replication-factor",
    "1" 
};
TopicCommand.main(options);

Comment: Can you give a sample to delete the topic?

Comment: String[] options = new String[]{ "--delete", "--zookeeper", "zk-host:port", "--topic", "your_topic_name"};
TopicCommand.main(options);

Comment: Thanks works perfectly. I asked from kafka user list, they suggested to use bash script.